# Why are colors not visible in the vuetify buttons?

Tags: vue.js, button, vuetify.js

[image]
i have made a card for sign in and there are no colours on any of the created components. the bottom of card consitst of two button but even those colors are not visible. i have attached the template section of my code. even the blue color of text fields is not visible. what can be the possible error?

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <v-container>
      <v-layout wrap>
        <v-row>
          <v-col cols="5">
            <v-img
              src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/programmer-working-flat-style_52683-15041.jpg?w=740"
              width="500"
              height="400"
            ></v-img>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="7" align-self="end">
            <v-flex sm12 md-8 offset-md3>
              <v-card elevation="6"  width="700">
                <v-card-title>
                  <v-layout align-center justify-space-between>
                    <h3 class="headline">Sign In</h3>
                  </v-layout>
                </v-card-title>
                <v-divider></v-divider>
                <v-card-text>
                  <p>Sign in with your username and password:</p>

                  <v-text-field
                      
                    autofocus
                    label="Email"
                    v-model="email"
                    type="email"
                  ></v-text-field>
                  <v-text-field
                    outline
                    hide-details
                    label="Password"
                    type="password"
                    v-model="password"
                  ></v-text-field>
                </v-card-text>
                <br />
                <v-divider></v-divider>
                <v-container class="px-5" >
                  <v-checkbox
                    class="pl-1"
                    dense
                    label="Remember Me"
                  ></v-checkbox>
                </v-container>
                <v-card-actions>
                  <v-btn class="green--text" color="info" flat to="/forgotdialogue">
                  Forgot password?
                  </v-btn>
                  <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                  <!-- <landingpage :username="username"></landingpage> -->
                  <v-btn @click="signUp" color="info">
                    <v-icon left>mdi-lock</v-icon>
                    Signup
                  </v-btn>
                </v-card-actions>
              </v-card>
            </v-flex>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: This code snippet is not running. Can you please add a working snippet so that we can look into that.

Comment: I have copied your code and run it, it works here. Maybe your setup is wrong with styles loading or something https://codepen.io/kunukn/pen/rNYwONO/e52764665b526c6ce3d64149a674bed3?editors=1100

Comment: i have tried everything but i am not able to get colors in entire page. i also tried installing vuetify package again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it
i just had to change my App.vue file.
in App.vue I included the code in between **v-app** tags. After this all the colors were restored. Read about it here in this vuetify page https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/application/